# Molding an object - Negative mold

Tags: modeling

I am trying to use my 3D Scanner and 3D Printer to make Molding of the objects using non printable materials.

For instance, if I 3D Scan a cup I get an OBJ / STL model ready to work with. But I would like to make a mold of it. Does blender have any resource to "invert" the solid? Then I woul print the mold and pour the material inside this "bucket" of mold.

Thank you.
Best,
Rick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a boolean modifier to substract one object from another:

The original object.
[image]

Add a cube that intersects your original object (this will become your mold).

[image]

On the cube apply a boolean modifier, choose difference and select the original object.

[image]

hide the original object (delete it or move it to another layer)

[image]

once you are happy with the results you can choose to apply the modifier.

EDIT: there is also a add on that removes the step of using a modifier. [Download](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/BoolTool). It has it's own tab. Just follow the steps above but instead of using a Boolean modifier use the 'direct' section in the 'booltool' tab, which is on the right side of the 3D view

Comment: Great Cegaton! Just one more thing... the cube generate is empty. Any fast/easy way to make it solid inside/in-filled? Thanks!

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5849/how-do-i-create-a-solid-object-cube

Comment: check out also http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/PrintToolbox