# How to produce an object that fills another objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a scanned object that looks like a complex bowl. I would like to make another object that fills the bowl as if it is liquid poured into the bowl. Ending up with two models that are positive and negative of each other. I hope that makes sense. I am new to this software.

Is this possible to do in Blender?

Comment: can you provide some screen shots

Comment: I found my answer here:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/molding-an-object-negative-mold