# Inverting, Mold Making, Booleans, Shrink Wrap

Tags: shrinkwrap, boolean-modifier

Blender Newbie.

I read through these related threads, but they don't provide an answer or fix. Also watch several YouTube videos. Nothing seems to work.

[What is the most efficient way to invert a mesh so as to inform a key, coupler or mold?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/76572/163845)

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15548

I'm trying to make a mold of a muscle mesh I downloaded and cut into segments for 3d printing.

[image: Muscle mesh to become a mold]

[image: Muscle mesh to become a mold]

I tried to find a way to just invert the mesh from a positive to a negative. The mold doesn't need to be thick so the outside surface can be a few millimetres.

I also tried using a shrink wrap modifier on a plane over the mesh and this is what happened.

[image: before shrink wrap]

[image: After shrink wrap]

I tried Booleans and nothing happens. Some of the Boolean fixes I found on YouTube suggested adding a solidify modifier to the mesh, so I have one added to it. Another suggestion was to add vertices to the cube, that didn't work. I've also played with Boolean settings (Fast, exact, self intersect, hole tolerant, etc.)

[image: Boolean modifier added to cube, mesh as target]

[image: wire view showing nothing happened]

Is there a way to just invert the mesh from a positive to a negative? Or any suggestions for the shrink wrap or boolean methods to work? Maybe something wrong with my mesh settings?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here's a link to the stl I'm trying to invert or make a boolean with.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L8Eh_eMfMe01wAxOsUD8mmWwoPm29G2J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it needs an authorization, could you please fix that or use another platform?

Comment: Apologies, fixed:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L8Eh_eMfMe01wAxOsUD8mmWwoPm29G2J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that the boolean doesn't work, it works fine, are you trying to create a plaster mold or something like that?

Comment: Nothing happens when I add a Boolean. Yep, I’m just trying to create a one sided negative mold, no keys or border necessary. I think I found a fix. I just added a solidify modifier and then set the thickness to a negative number. this inverted the front face. I think flipping the normals does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this method. First make sure that your topology is clean (you can use the *Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox* addon:

[image]

Then create a plane that you stick to the surface of your object with the help of the *Snap to* option:

[image]

Extrude the plane a bit (I guess the shape will depend on how you want to cut the mold afterwards):

[image]

Extrude to give thickness to this plane so that it contains your original object:

[image]

Give a *Boolean* modifier to your plane:

[image]

Apply the modifier, you get your mold, again check its topology with the *Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox* addon:

[image]

If you need your mold to be in several pieces, you need to separate the plane in different pieces before the extrusion.

You could also create your mold with a fattening operation of your original object, then remesh in *Sculpt* mode then remesh in *Object* mode, but it will need more steps.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm using this method now!

Comment: Oh OK, glad it works, do you have to create a mold in separate parts?

Comment: No just the front of the surface. So I wouldn't need to make the backside. What I did was run the checks, and nothing came back bad on cont. edges or non-flat faces, but it did have some high values on non manifold edge and zero faces. So I'm watching tutorials on how to clean up topology. Then I'm doing what you suggested by creating a plane, give it some thickness and snapping it. I'm also going to try applying a shrinkwrap mod and then doing the boolean. I'll post an update tomorrow hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Mesh is not really solid, it just has a little marker on each face called a normal that tells that face which way is out. If you invert the normals, technically, the mesh is now “negative”, but then you need to add something around it to be the outside wall. That’s simple enough, add a cube mesh around the cavity. For a mold, you also need to add some kind of tubing so that Stuffs can get in and air can get out. That’s where a Boolean operation might be helpful, unifying a cylinder (with its normals also inverted) with the cube and the cavity.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link explaining the first part? I’m a bit lost about the outside wall? Like create a border around the mesh with planes? How would I invert the mesh, because I actually just need this to be a negative? I won’t need the tubing, because I’m just pouring latex directly into the mold in layers, it’s not like a traditional mold.

Comment: If you make the shape you have a negative, then it’s an air bubble in an entire universe of solid mold material. So, you add an outside wall where the mold stops and air starts again.

Comment: I say again, mesh is not solid. It’s only a surface, and each face has a marker that tells it which way is out. You need to flip those. They’re called normals.

Comment: You will need at least one hole in the mold, or you’ll have nowhere to pour into! 

Comment: I will try to make a visual step-by-step…

Comment: Hmm, I'm having a bit of trouble...

Comment: All good thank you, I think I got it to work!